# Dynamically disable tooltip when element becomes disabled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, single-page-application

I am trying to prevent a twitter bootstrap tooltip from showing when the element is disabled. I am able to do so with the following code:

```
app.directive("tooltip",function(){
    return {
          restrict:"A",
          require: 'tooltipDirection',
          link:function(scope,element,attrs,directionController){

               attrs.$observe('ngDisabled',function(){


                   console.log("ngDisabled has changed: " + attrs.ngDisabled);

               });                  

               if(scope.$eval(attrs.ngDisabled)!=true){

                 $(element).attr('title',attrs.tooltip).tooltip({placement:directionController.direction});
               }
           }
     };

});
```

However, this only works when the page loads and the element is already disabled. I need a way of dynamically disabling the tooltip. For example, if I click on a button (edit) which changes the value of a scope variable(editing_bln), the 2nd button button (save) becomes disabled via ngDisabled and the scope variable, editing_bln. I now want the tooltip to be disabled as well - which it is not. I tried using attrs.$observe in the link function, however, that is also getting called when the page loads and not when the variable, editing_bln, changes. Here is the button code:

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{'btn-danger':editing_bln}" class="btn btn-mini" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;" ng-click="editing_bln = !editing_bln"><i tooltip-direction="top" tooltip="Click to Edit Content" ng-class="{'icon-white':editing_bln}" class="icon-pencil"></i></button>

<button ng-disabled="editing_bln" type="button" class="btn btn-mini" style="margin-top:10px;" ng-click="responseAdd()"><i tooltip-direction="top" tooltip="Add response to group."  class="icon-plus"></i></button>
```

I am guessing that I am missing the mark in the linking function. Thanks for any and all replies.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try to do is set the tooltip-trigger to a unrecognized trigger, which essentially causes the tooltip to not trigger at all:

```
<button ng-disabled="editing_bln" type="button" class="btn btn-mini" 
        style="margin-top:10px;" ng-click="responseAdd()">
    <i tooltip-direction="top" tooltip="Add response to group." 
       tooltip-trigger={{ editing_bln ? 'none' : 'mouseenter'}}" 
       class="icon-plus"></i>
</button>
```